# Logger name in nLog log truncated

Tags: nlog

I've just inherited a project where the previous team were using nLog(which is not a logger I'm familiar with). There is an annoying issue with the logs, where the logger name portion of the log file is truncated to 40 characters.I can't understand what it causing this, and this output makes the log files painful to work with / debugging issues difficult.

The project is configuring the log targets(FileTarget) programmatically,the logger layout is:

```
${longdate}\t[${threadid}]\t${level:uppercase=true}\t${logger}\t${mdc:item=identifier}\t${message}\t${exception:format=tostring}
```

Log File Output:

```
# Cleaned up for brevity
2017-08-15 ... [1]  INFO MyProject.Some.Namespace.TruncatedFullNa Resolve: ClientDevice=Desktop, ClientOS=Unknown
2017-08-15 ... [1] DEBUG MyProject.Some.Namespace.WhyCantISeeTheN System code from context: 0x004F
2017-08-15 ... [1] DEBUG MyProject.Some.Namespace.SubNameSpace.Wh Resolve Starting
2017-08-15 ... [1] ERROR MyProject.Some.Namespace.SubNameSpace.Wh Resolve failed -  ....
```

Logger Creation (per class):
`private static readonly NLog.ILogger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`

Web.config:

```
<nlog>
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="Custom.Logging" />
    </extensions>
    <targets>
      <target name="AggregateLevelRollingFile" type="AggregateLevelRollingFile" />
      <target name="LevelRollingFile" type="LevelRollingFile" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="AggregateLevelRollingFile,LevelRollingFile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

**Update** - Add custom target code

```
public AggregateLevelRollingFile()
{
  var baseDir = ResolveLogDir();
  var applicationName = AppContext.GetName();
  FileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}", baseDir, applicationName,"{shortdate}.All.log");
  ArchiveFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}", baseDir, applicationName, "${shortdate}_{##}.All.log");
  MaxArchiveFiles = 1000000;
  ArchiveAboveSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
  Layout =
      new LayoutWithHeaderAndFooter
      {
          Header = new SimpleLayout("Time\tThread\tLevel\tLogger\tMessage\tException"),
          Layout = new SimpleLayout("${longdate}\t[${threadid}]\t${level:uppercase=true}\t${logger}\t${mdc:item=identifier}\t${message}\t${exception:format=tostring}")

      };
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a Custom Target "Custom.Logging".  Have you checked in that target code to see it is truncating the logger text?

Comment: @John yea, I looked at it, and I cant see anything that would be the offender. I updated the question to include the code from one of them (the other is effectively identical)

Comment: Looks ok, some things you can try is create a new File Target and bypass your target to see if you have the same issue.  Maybe Pad the logger like ${logger:padding=100} to see if that increases it and does not truncate it. Maybe the \t are messing with it, replace with spaces just to see.  These are guesses and things to try.